# Shift movie horizontally for side by side

Tags: imovie, crop, macos

I have two videos where the action appears on the left side of the frame.  Using iMovie version 10.0.9, I use the side-by-side overlay.  The bottom (right) video is overlapped by the top video so the action is not seen.  How can I shift the bottom video to the right so that the action appears on the right side of the side-by-side?  Can I edit the right side video 1st so the action has been shifted to the right side of the frame?

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for an answer that uses just iMovie or QuickTime editing feature but until there is an alternative provided, I will post this answer using the free VideoPad app (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/videopad-video-editor-free/id846931335).

VideoPad has a Position Video Effect that allows me to slide the video to the right (the left area is filled in black).  Saving this I can now position it side by side and have the action appear on the right half back in iMovie.

Support for positioning video within the frame is what I need in iMovie